# Performance difference between growing vectors using c() versus assignment in R

Tags: r, performance, memory

I'm trying to put together some materials on the perils of growing data structures in R in a `for` loop. I want to be able to explain what's going on under the hood that drives the difference in performance, especially the huge memory differences in the approaches.

I'm contrasting 3 approaches:

- growing a results vector through the use of the `c()` function.
- growing a results vector through assignment.
- pre-allocating the results vector.

Consider the following reprex:

```r
library(pryr)

x <- runif(10, min = 1, max = 100)

# Create function that appends to result vector through c
for_loop_c <- function(x, print = TRUE) {
    y <- NULL
    for (i in seq_along(x)) {
        y <- c(y, sqrt(x[i]))
        if (print) {
            print(c(address(y), refs(y)))
        }
    }
    y
}
# Create function that appends to result vector through assignment
for_loop_assign <- function(x, print = TRUE) {
    y <- NULL
    for (i in seq_along(x)) {
        y[i] <- sqrt(x[i])
        if (print) {
            print(c(address(y), refs(y)))
        }
    }
    y
}

# Create function that preallocates result vector
for_loop_preallocate <- function(x, print = TRUE) {
    y <- numeric(length(x))

    for (i in seq_along(x)) {
        y[i] <- sqrt(x[i])

        if (print) {
        print(c(address(y), refs(y)))
        }
    }
    y
}

# Run functions and check for copies by changes to address and refs
for_loop_c(x)
#> [1] "0x11bfbdbf8" "1"          
#> [1] "0x11bf9b948" "1"          
#> [1] "0x11bf9f398" "1"          
#> [1] "0x11bf9f258" "1"          
#> [1] "0x11bf82938" "1"          
#> [1] "0x11bf82778" "1"          
#> [1] "0x11bf825b8" "1"          
#> [1] "0x11bf823f8" "1"          
#> [1] "0x11bf55768" "1"          
#> [1] "0x11bf55608" "1"
#>  [1] 3.976751 6.148983 9.373843 7.928771 5.321063 7.238960 5.707823 9.921684
#>  [9] 7.643938 3.764301
for_loop_assign(x)
#> [1] "0x11c2ee4e8" "1"          
#> [1] "0x11c2bb608" "1"          
#> [1] "0x11c2b6c28" "1"          
#> [1] "0x11c2b6ae8" "1"          
#> [1] "0x11c224d48" "1"          
#> [1] "0x11c224b88" "1"          
#> [1] "0x11c2249c8" "1"          
#> [1] "0x11c224808" "1"          
#> [1] "0x11c2d3748" "1"          
#> [1] "0x11c2d35e8" "1"
#>  [1] 3.976751 6.148983 9.373843 7.928771 5.321063 7.238960 5.707823 9.921684
#>  [9] 7.643938 3.764301
for_loop_preallocate(x)
#> [1] "0x11c5b8888" "1"          
#> [1] "0x11c5b8888" "1"          
#> [1] "0x11c5b8888" "1"          
#> [1] "0x11c5b8888" "1"          
#> [1] "0x11c5b8888" "1"          
#> [1] "0x11c5b8888" "1"          
#> [1] "0x11c5b8888" "1"          
#> [1] "0x11c5b8888" "1"          
#> [1] "0x11c5b8888" "1"          
#> [1] "0x11c5b8888" "1"
#>  [1] 3.976751 6.148983 9.373843 7.928771 5.321063 7.238960 5.707823 9.921684
#>  [9] 7.643938 3.764301

# Create a bigger example x for benchmarking
x <- runif(10000, min = 1, max = 100)

# Benchmark
bench::mark(
    for_loop_c(x, print = FALSE),
    for_loop_assign(x, print = FALSE),
    for_loop_preallocate(x, print = FALSE)
)
#> Warning: Some expressions had a GC in every iteration; so filtering is disabled.
#> # A tibble: 3 × 6
#>   expression                                  min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc
#>   <bch:expr>                             <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>
#> 1 for_loop_c(x, print = FALSE)              106ms 114.92ms      8.57  381.96MB
#> 2 for_loop_assign(x, print = FALSE)        1.19ms   1.27ms    621.      1.66MB
#> 3 for_loop_preallocate(x, print = FALSE) 381.71µs 386.88µs   2554.     78.17KB
#> # … with 1 more variable: `gc/sec` <dbl>


library(profmem)
gc()
#>           used (Mb) gc trigger (Mb) limit (Mb) max used (Mb)
#> Ncells  824931 44.1    1409852 75.3         NA  1409852 75.3
#> Vcells 1483448 11.4    8388608 64.0      32768  8388585 64.0

pm1 <- profmem({
    y <- NULL
    for (i in seq_along(x)) {
        y <- c(y, sqrt(x[i]))
    }

})


pm2 <- profmem({
    y <- NULL
    for (i in seq_along(x)) {
        y[i] <- sqrt(x[i])
    }
    y

})

# Number of times memory allocation occurred
pm1$bytes |> length()
#> [1] 10061
pm2$bytes |> length()
#> [1] 174
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-02 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Session info

```r
sessioninfo::session_info()
#> ─ Session info ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#>  setting  value
#>  version  R version 4.2.1 (2022-06-23)
#>  os       macOS Monterey 12.3.1
#>  system   aarch64, darwin20
#>  ui       X11
#>  language (EN)
#>  collate  en_US.UTF-8
#>  ctype    en_US.UTF-8
#>  tz       Europe/Athens
#>  date     2023-02-02
#>  pandoc   2.19.2 @ /Applications/RStudio.app/Contents/Resources/app/quarto/bin/tools/ (via rmarkdown)
#> 
#> ─ Packages ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#>  ! package     * version date (UTC) lib source
#>    bench         1.1.2   2021-11-30 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>    cli           3.6.0   2023-01-09 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>    codetools     0.2-18  2020-11-04 [2] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
#>  P digest        0.6.29  2021-12-01 [?] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  P evaluate      0.16    2022-08-09 [?] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
#>    fansi         1.0.3   2022-03-24 [2] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  P fastmap       1.1.0   2021-01-25 [?] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>    fs            1.5.2   2021-12-08 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  P glue          1.6.2   2022-02-24 [?] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  P highr         0.9     2021-04-16 [?] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
#>  P htmltools     0.5.3   2022-07-18 [?] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  P knitr         1.40    2022-08-24 [?] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>    lifecycle     1.0.3   2022-10-07 [2] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  P magrittr      2.0.3   2022-03-30 [?] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>    pillar        1.8.1   2022-08-19 [2] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>    pkgconfig     2.0.3   2019-09-22 [2] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  P profmem     * 0.6.0   2020-12-13 [?] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>    pryr        * 0.1.6   2023-01-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>    purrr         1.0.1   2023-01-10 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  P R.cache       0.16.0  2022-07-21 [?] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  P R.methodsS3   1.8.2   2022-06-13 [?] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  P R.oo          1.25.0  2022-06-12 [?] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  P R.utils       2.12.2  2022-11-11 [?] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>    Rcpp          1.0.9   2022-07-08 [2] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>    reprex        2.0.2   2022-08-17 [2] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>    rlang         1.0.6   2022-09-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  P rmarkdown     2.16    2022-08-24 [?] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>    rstudioapi    0.14    2022-08-22 [2] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>    sessioninfo   1.2.2   2021-12-06 [2] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  P stringi       1.7.8   2022-07-11 [?] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  P stringr       1.4.1   2022-08-20 [?] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  P styler        1.9.0   2023-01-15 [?] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>    tibble        3.1.8   2022-07-22 [2] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>    utf8          1.2.2   2021-07-24 [2] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  P vctrs         0.5.1   2022-11-16 [?] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>    withr         2.5.0   2022-03-03 [2] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  P xfun          0.33    2022-09-12 [?] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
#>  P yaml          2.3.5   2022-02-21 [?] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#> 
#>  [1] /*/renv/library/R-4.2/aarch64-apple-darwin20
#>  [2] /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2-arm64/Resources/library
#> 
#>  P ── Loaded and on-disk path mismatch.
#> 
#> ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
```

I understand why preallocating is the most efficient (no copies made, address the same at each iteration).

I *think* what's going on is that in `c()` a full copy of `y` is made within the function and then another one when assigning back to `y` whereas when growing using assignment, a copy is made (hence changes in address) but only made during assignment?

My questions are:

- Is my general understanding correct?
- What exactly is going on in terms of copies and their size between approach 1 & 2 that can explain the huge difference in memory used and number of memory allocation events?
- Is there a good way to demonstrate exactly what's going on between approaches 1 & 2?

EDIT

Given the feedback by @Kevin-Ushey & @alexis_laz I've adapted my examples to record the cumulative number of address changes at each iteration:

```r
library(pryr)
library(ggplot2)

# Create function that appends to result vector through c
# Collect cumulative number of address changes per iteration
for_loop_c <- function(x, count_addr = TRUE) {
    y <- NULL
    y_addr <- address(y)
    cum_address_n <- 0
    cum_address_n_v <- numeric(length(x))

    for (i in seq_along(x)) {
        y <- c(y, sqrt(x[i]))
            if (address(y) != y_addr) {
                cum_address_n <- cum_address_n + 1
                y_addr <- address(y)
            }

        cum_address_n_v[i] <- cum_address_n
    }
    data.frame(i = seq_along(cum_address_n_v),
               cum_address_n = cum_address_n_v,
               mode = "c")
}

# Create function that appends to result vector through assignment.
# Collect cumulative number of address changes per iteration
for_loop_assign <- function(x) {
    y <- NULL
    y_addr <- address(y)
    cum_address_n <- 0
    cum_address_n_v <- numeric(length(x))

    for (i in seq_along(x)) {

        y[i] <- sqrt(x[i])
            if (address(y) != y_addr) {
                cum_address_n <- cum_address_n + 1
                y_addr <- address(y)
            }
        cum_address_n_v[i] <- cum_address_n
    }
    data.frame(i = seq_along(cum_address_n_v),
               cum_address_n = cum_address_n_v,
               mode = "assign")
}




x <- runif(10000, min = 1, max = 100)

rbind(for_loop_c(x), for_loop_assign(x)) |>
    ggplot(aes(x = i, y = cum_address_n, colour = mode)) +
    geom_line()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-02-03 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Session info

```r
sessioninfo::session_info()
#> ─ Session info ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#>  setting  value
#>  version  R version 4.2.1 (2022-06-23)
#>  os       macOS Monterey 12.3.1
#>  system   aarch64, darwin20
#>  ui       X11
#>  language (EN)
#>  collate  en_US.UTF-8
#>  ctype    en_US.UTF-8
#>  tz       Europe/Athens
#>  date     2023-02-03
#>  pandoc   2.19.2 @ /Applications/RStudio.app/Contents/Resources/app/quarto/bin/tools/ (via rmarkdown)
#> 
#> ─ Packages ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#>  ! package     * version date (UTC) lib source
#>  P assertthat    0.2.1   2019-03-21 [?] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>    cli           3.6.0   2023-01-09 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>    codetools     0.2-18  2020-11-04 [2] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
#>  P colorspace    2.0-3   2022-02-21 [?] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
#>    curl          4.3.2   2021-06-23 [2] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>    DBI           1.1.3   2022-06-18 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  P digest        0.6.29  2021-12-01 [?] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>    dplyr         1.0.10  2022-09-01 [2] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  P evaluate      0.16    2022-08-09 [?] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
#>    fansi         1.0.3   2022-03-24 [2] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  P farver        2.1.1   2022-07-06 [?] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
#>  P fastmap       1.1.0   2021-01-25 [?] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>    fs            1.5.2   2021-12-08 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>    generics      0.1.3   2022-07-05 [2] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  P ggplot2     * 3.4.0   2022-11-04 [?] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  P glue          1.6.2   2022-02-24 [?] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  P gtable        0.3.1   2022-09-01 [?] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
#>  P highr         0.9     2021-04-16 [?] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
#>  P htmltools     0.5.3   2022-07-18 [?] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>    httr          1.4.4   2022-08-17 [2] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  P knitr         1.40    2022-08-24 [?] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  P labeling      0.4.2   2020-10-20 [?] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
#>    lifecycle     1.0.3   2022-10-07 [2] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  P magrittr      2.0.3   2022-03-30 [?] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>    mime          0.12    2021-09-28 [2] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  P munsell       0.5.0   2018-06-12 [?] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
#>    pillar        1.8.1   2022-08-19 [2] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>    pkgconfig     2.0.3   2019-09-22 [2] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>    pryr        * 0.1.6   2023-01-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>    purrr         1.0.1   2023-01-10 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  P R.cache       0.16.0  2022-07-21 [?] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  P R.methodsS3   1.8.2   2022-06-13 [?] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  P R.oo          1.25.0  2022-06-12 [?] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  P R.utils       2.12.2  2022-11-11 [?] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  P R6            2.5.1   2021-08-19 [?] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>    Rcpp          1.0.9   2022-07-08 [2] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>    reprex        2.0.2   2022-08-17 [2] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>    rlang         1.0.6   2022-09-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  P rmarkdown     2.16    2022-08-24 [?] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>    rstudioapi    0.14    2022-08-22 [2] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  P scales        1.2.1   2022-08-20 [?] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
#>    sessioninfo   1.2.2   2021-12-06 [2] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  P stringi       1.7.8   2022-07-11 [?] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  P stringr       1.4.1   2022-08-20 [?] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  P styler        1.9.0   2023-01-15 [?] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>    tibble        3.1.8   2022-07-22 [2] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  P tidyselect    1.2.0   2022-10-10 [?] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>    utf8          1.2.2   2021-07-24 [2] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  P vctrs         0.5.1   2022-11-16 [?] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>    withr         2.5.0   2022-03-03 [2] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  P xfun          0.33    2022-09-12 [?] CRAN (R 4.2.1)
#>    xml2          1.3.3   2021-11-30 [2] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  P yaml          2.3.5   2022-02-21 [?] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#> 
#>  [1] /*/optimise-r/renv/library/R-4.2/aarch64-apple-darwin20
#>  [2] /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2-arm64/Resources/library
#> 
#>  P ── Loaded and on-disk path mismatch.
#> 
#> ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
```

My interpretation given the feedback in answers and comments is that:

- Using assignment results in much fewer changes in address which tapers off when the size of `y` increases to the point where [it's no longer being managed through R's small vector pool and is instead being managed through requests to the OS for additional memory](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/memory.html). I think what this means is that, when dealing with larger vectors, R can modify the object in place when using assignment **between requests for additional memory** and that because the modification in each iteration is so small, the algorithm can run for quite a few iterations without requesting additional memory.
- Using `c()` triggers a change in address at each iteration. **I'm still however unclear whether this is because `c()` modifies `y` within and therefore triggers a copy or whether is has to do with assigning a full new `y` back to `y` rather than assigning a single additional element?**

Comment: When using `[<-` (sub-assignment) past the length of a vector, R -whenever deemed appropriate- enlarges the vector by an additional 5% (and that "truelength" can not be accessible via `length`), so R has a hidden 5% more memory pre-occupied to continue growing the vector "in place".  When using `c`, each time a new vector (of appropriate length) is allocated and `c` arguments are copied in the new vector. Binding the object created with `c` to a symbol (here "y") does not create any copy (unless that object is also referenced to another symbol or is being modified).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

R (since version 3.4.0) will allocate a bit of extra memory for atomic vectors, so that 'growing' such vectors via sub-assignment may not require a reallocation if some spare capacity is still available. This is discussed a bit in the *R Internals* manual here; see the references to the 'truelength' of a vector:

https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-ints.html#The-_0027data_0027

https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-ints.html#FOOT3

Hence, in the past, the common wisdom was "always pre-allocate your vectors" and "avoid for loops", but nowadays if the final capacity of your vector is unknown, growing vectors via sub-assignment may be a reasonable solution.

This, together with byte-compilation of functions, means that some of the common wisdom around avoiding for loops is no longer as true as it once was. (However, the best-performing R code will typically still be of a functional style, or will require carefully pre-allocating memory / vectors and avoiding frequent allocations.)

Comment: (just adding a comment to demonstrate this behaviour) Suppose we could extract "truelength" like `tl = function(x) gsub(".*tl=(.*)\\).*", "\\1", capture.output(.Internal(inspect(x))))`. Then compare `f1 = function(n) { y = NULL; tls = character(n); for(i in 1:n) { y[i] = i; tls[i] = tl(y) }; return(tls) }` with `f2 = function(n) { y = NULL; tls = character(n); for(i in 1:n) { y = c(y, i); tls[i] = tl(y) }; return(tls) }`. E.g. `f1(1e2); f2(1e2)`

Comment: Perhaps I am misinterpreting what a change in address means. (I've been using `address()` instead of `tracemem` because I'm writing up the demo in quarto in Rstudio where it seems to have odd behaviour). Does a change in address not necessarily mean a copy is made but could mean the object just now lives in a slightly expanded version of the original memory block? Also, is my interpretation of what's going on with `c()` correct?

Comment: @AnnaKrystalli : If you notice, the address does not change constantly with larger vectors after a certain point (`f = function(n) { y = NULL; for(i in 1:n) { y[i] = i; print(pryr::address(y)) } }; f(1e2)`). Also, assigning back to `y` (after `c(y, ...`) just increases the references of an object; it does not copy immediately.

Comment: @alexis_laz, re: change of address you are right! Thanks for pointing that out. re: object references in `c()`, I'm a little confused because at no point does the `ref` count increase in the c implementation. Is that because it happens within `c()` and removed immediately? And if so, what exactly is the difference between `c()` and assignment? is it because the whole object is being re-assigned to `y` in  the `c()` implementation whereas the assignment approach allows for modification in place between requests for more memory as the vector grows?